# Dynamic Height of Cells in Table View Not Working

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios, row-height

I have created one `table view`, which has 6 labels and 2 buttons. I am using autolayout. And I am getting data from the server.

**ViewController.cs**

```
public partial class CaseHistoryController : UIViewController
{
    private List<CaseSearchItem> caseSearchItems;
    CaseHistorySourceClass caseSearchSourceclass;

    public CaseHistoryController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        this.Title = "Case History";

        View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear.FromHexString("#DDDDDD", 1.0f);
        var task = GetCaseHistoryData();
    }

    private async Task GetCaseHistoryData()
    {
        caseSearchItems = await CaseHistoryServices.GetListCaseHistory();
        caseSearchSourceclass = new CaseHistorySourceClass(caseSearchItems);

        CaseHistorySourceClass.RowClicked += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var webController = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("UserInfoViewController") as UserInfoViewController;
            webController.caseSearchItem = (CaseSearchItem)sender;
            NavigationController.PushViewController(webController, true);
        };
        caseHistoryTableView.Source = caseSearchSourceclass;

        caseHistoryTableView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear.FromHexString("#DDDDDD", 1.0f);
        caseHistoryTableView.SectionHeaderHeight = 0.0f;
        caseHistoryTableView.SectionFooterHeight = 5.0f;
        caseHistoryTableView.ContentInset = new UIEdgeInsets(0, 0, 10.0f, 0);
    }

    public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
        caseHistoryTableView.ReloadData();
        caseHistoryTableView.RowHeight = UITableView.AutomaticDimension;
        caseHistoryTableView.EstimatedRowHeight = 145.0f;
    }

    public class CaseHistorySourceClass : UITableViewSource
    {
        private List<CaseSearchItem> caseSearchItems;
        public CaseSearchItem caseSearchItem;
        public static event EventHandler RowClicked;
        public CaseHistorySourceClass(List<CaseSearchItem> caseSearchItems)
        {
            this.caseSearchItems = caseSearchItems;
        }
        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            CaseHistoryTableCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(CaseHistoryTableCell.Key) as CaseHistoryTableCell ?? CaseHistoryTableCell.Create();
            var item = caseSearchItems[indexPath.Row];

            cell.BindData(item.Organization, item.Address, item.Doctor, item.UserName);
            cell.Layer.MasksToBounds = false;
            cell.Layer.CornerRadius = 10.0f;
            cell.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
            return cell;
        }

        public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            caseSearchItem = caseSearchItems[indexPath.Row];
            tableView.DeselectRow(indexPath, true);
            if (RowClicked != null)
                RowClicked(caseSearchItem, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
        {
            return caseSearchItems.Count;
        }
    }

}
```

**TableViewCell.cs**

```
public partial class CaseHistoryTableCell : UITableViewCell
{
     public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString("CaseHistoryTableCell");
     public static readonly UINib Nib;

     static CaseHistoryTableCell()
     {
          Nib = UINib.FromName("CaseHistoryTableCell", NSBundle.MainBundle);
     }

     public CaseHistoryTableCell(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
     {
         // Note: this .ctor should not contain any initialization logic.
     }

     public static CaseHistoryTableCell Create()
     {
         return (CaseHistoryTableCell)Nib.Instantiate(null, null)[0];
     }

     public void BindData(string hospitalLabel, string addressLabel, string drLabel, string patientLabel)
     {
         this.lbl_hospitalName.Text = hospitalLabel;
         this.lbl_address.Text = addressLabel;

         this.lbl_drName.Text = drLabel;
         this.lbl_patientName.Text = patientLabel;

         this.lbl_address.TextColor = UIColor.Clear.FromHexString("#000000", 0.54f);
         this.lbl_patientName.TextColor = UIColor.Clear.FromHexString("#000000", 0.54f);
         this.lbl_hospitalName.TextColor = UIColor.Clear.FromHexString("#000000", 0.87f);
         this.lbl_drName.TextColor = UIColor.Clear.FromHexString("#000000", 0.87f);
            this.btn_createAppointment.SetTitleColor(UIColor.Clear.FromHexString("#0072BA", 1.0f), UIControlState.Normal);
            this.btn_viewDetail.SetTitleColor(UIColor.Clear.FromHexString("#0072BA", 1.0f), UIControlState.Normal);

       }

       public override CGRect Frame
       {
            get
            {
                return base.Frame;
            }

            set
            {
                value.Y += 4;
                value.Height -= 2 * 4;
                base.Frame = value;
            }
      }

 }
```

**What I want is:**

I want to make all cell height dynamic. But every time, the second cell is not taking adjustment.

**What I have tried:**

**1.)**

In `ViewDidAppear`, I set the following:

```
public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
{
    base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
    caseHistoryTableView.ReloadData();
    caseHistoryTableView.RowHeight = UITableView.AutomaticDimension;
    caseHistoryTableView.EstimatedRowHeight = 145.0f;
}
```

**2.)**

In `GetCell` method, I add the cells this way:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    CaseHistoryTableCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(CaseHistoryTableCell.Key) as CaseHistoryTableCell ?? CaseHistoryTableCell.Create();
    var item = caseSearchItems[indexPath.Row];
    cell.BindData(item.Organization, item.Address, item.Doctor, item.UserName);

    cell.Layer.MasksToBounds = false;
    cell.Layer.CornerRadius = 10.0f;
    cell.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
    cell.SetNeedsLayout();
    cell.LayoutIfNeeded();
    return cell;
}
```

But I still get below output:

---

The second cell in not taking automatic height.

[image]

**Label 1 constraint :(hospital Label)**

[image]

**Label 2 constaint :(Address Label)**

[image]

Comment: the whole thing is manageable by `autolayout` and `tableviewdelegates`

Comment: @TinuDahiya as I am saying in my question I am using `autoLayout` but it is not work see the question again.

Comment: Change the label height relation from `equalto(=)` to `greaterthatequalto(>=)`. And i already read your ques, there must be issue in any constraint.

Comment: Have you set numberOfLine = 0 in your storyboard? Could you please share your autolayout screen shot.

Comment: @DheerajD yes i have set in the `storyboard`.

Comment: @TinuDahiya `constraint` is set well because the first cell is see very well.

Comment: Share your constraints @Ironman , most probably there must be something missing

Comment: Try put the "ReloadData()" method after "EstimatedRowHeight=145.0f" ?

Comment: @TinuDahiya i update the question.

Comment: @TinuDahiya `lable1` is `hospital` dark black color and `label2` is `address` light black .

Comment: If you can show me your prototype cell screen shot then i can more estimate the result. @Ironman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add height of the both labels, as per the your requirement for single line height, now add relationship for both the constraints from `equalto(=)` to `greaterthanorequalto(>=)`

see below image.

[image]

Now Run and recheck, if face any problem now than let me know.

Comment: wait i try and come back soon.

Comment: don't forget your label line property is 0 from story board. Every label and view you have in prototype cell must have top and bottom constraint as per there hierarchy. And If all these component is in UIView then do the give relationship height with that UIView @Ironman

Answer (score 0):

Just calculate the height of label according to the string size which will be shown up there, just add the below method by which you will get the height and manage the label size accordingly.

```
 func heightForWithFont(font: UIFont, width: CGFloat, insets: UIEdgeInsets) -> CGFloat {

        let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: width + insets.left + insets.right, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
        label.font = font
        label.sizeToFit()
        return label.frame.height + insets.top + insets.bottom
    }
```

Hope it works:)

Comment: you have to calculate all the labels height and then add them together and pass it into heightForRowAtIndexPath,

Comment: call the heightForWithFont method in cellForRow before initialisation of the cell